# migrate a google compute engine instance from one account to another

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to migrate a google compute engine instance from one account to another... any easiest tips?

I have looked through the control panel and tried to find a way to export an image and then import to the new account but cannot see this option.

Answer (score 4):

*Preliminary note: I'm assuming that when you say "from one account to another", you actually mean "from one project to another", which may or may not belong to the same account. Just in case I'm misunderstanding concepts here.*

It's not exactly a trivial task, but it's doable.

Let's say you have **Project A**, where your original instance resides; and **Project B**, where you want to replicate the aforementioned instance. Basically, what you have to do is:

1. In **Project A**, you have to create a so-called "image bundle" of the persistent disk of interest attached to the instance. This process yields a compressed snapshot of your disk in .tar.gz format, which you can later on upload to Google Cloud Storage for inter-project sharing. This part is explained step-by-step here: [Export an Image to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#export_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage). When you're done, remember to (temporarily) share your tarball in order to allow Project B to download it. **Pro tip:** You can execute the commands shown in that guide in a very convenient way from a [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-shell/docs/).
2. In **Project B**, now you have to create an image from the tarball we just created in step 1. This is described in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#use_saved_image), although it simply boils down to this command:

   `$ gcloud compute images create <IMAGE_NAME> --source-uri gs://<PROJECT-A_BUCKET>/<FILE>.tar.gz`

At this point, you can go ahead and create a new instance in Project B using this image as the source for its boot disk, making it identical to the original instance in Project A.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response asamarin ... you are correct, from one project to another", which DOES NOT belong to the same account. I'll have a go at your suggestions : )

Comment: @CameronCross, if you have other customs settings/resources in the source VM (networking things, other disks, etc), be sure to duplicate them separately in the target instance, too. One thing you won't be able to duplicate is the permanent IP (if any) assigned to the source VM -- you'll get a new one in the target VM; so you may have to adjust DNS too!

Comment: Seems I am stuck on the first step "Export an Image to Google Cloud Storage". I am using the SSH console inside my instance and typed the following with the following error.... gcloud compute disks create temporary-disk
NAME ZONE SIZE_GB TYPE STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Unable to fetch a list of zones. Specifying [--zone] may fix this issue:
 - Insufficient Permission

Comment: You're seeing that error because the instance you're issuing the commands from wasn't created with the right scopes. That's one of the reasons I suggested you to use Cloud Shell: this ephemeral machine will be provisioned with all necessary scopes and permissions out of the box, so you don't have to worry about it. Alternatively, if you still want to use regular instances to do the job, you'll need to create a new one first, since scopes are granted only at creation time and cannot be modified later on. This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using)

Comment: Is this even possible anymore? I am trying to get a .tar.gz exported from either an instance of a (disk) snapshot but can't seem to do so anywhere (?)